# Is there a functional difference between Assert.IsNotNull(·) Assert.AreNotEqual(null,·)?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

Is there a functional difference  between `Assert.IsNotNull(·)` `Assert.AreNotEqual(null,·)`?

I prefer the first, as it's more readable. A colleague used the second, I wondered if there's also a functional difference. I know comparing objects to null can sometimes be weird (the difference between `.Equals` and `==`).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you can also do `Assert.IsFalse(obj == null)` and `Assert.IsTrue(obj != null)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.

The long answer involves looking at the actual source code. I retrieved this using a decompiler, so some of it may look a little weird. The comments are added by me.

```
// The IsNotNull overload that takes only "value" calls this one internally
public static void IsNotNull(object value, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
  if (value != null)
    return;
  Assert.HandleFail("Assert.IsNotNull", message, parameters);
}

// The AreNotEqual that takes only "notExpected" and "actual" calls this one internally
public static void AreNotEqual<T>(T notExpected, T actual, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
  if (!object.Equals((object) notExpected, (object) actual))
    return;
  Assert.HandleFail("Assert.AreNotEqual", (string) FrameworkMessages.AreNotEqualFailMsg(message == null ? (object) string.Empty : (object) Assert.ReplaceNulls((object) message), (object) Assert.ReplaceNulls((object) notExpected), (object) Assert.ReplaceNulls((object) actual)), parameters);
}
```

It's true that there's a difference between comparing with `==` and `Equals`, but it shouldn't make a difference when you're comparing to null. As you can see, `AreNotEqual` casts the input values to `object` and uses the standard static `Equals` implementation on the `object` class, which is implemented as follows:

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
{
    if (objA==objB) {
        return true;
    } 
    if (objA==null || objB==null) {
        return false; 
    } 
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

In my opinion, `IsNotNull` is clearer than `AreNotEqual`, and the error message if gives when the assert fails is probably easier to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 1):

`IsNotNull`: Verifies that the specified object is not null. The assertion fails if it is null.

`AreNotEqual`: Verifies that two specified objects are not equal. The assertion fails if the objects are equal.

So the function `IsNotNull` only verifies that **one** specified object is not null, while `AreNotEqual` compares **two** objects. The `IsNotNull` function will be a (little) bit faster.